# How is a VM isolated from the physical host?

Tags: virtualization

I was thinking about virtualisation and how to explain it to a non-technical person and one of the things that I was wondering was how to explain the way that a VM is isolated and seperate from the phyiscal machine (so I can have a virus on a VM but this would never effect my physical host, right?).

How does this technology work exactly? As I am a programmer, when I think of isolating processes, I think of using appdomains (I work with C# primarily).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything (well pretty much everything) you do in a virtual machine is basically emulated (or passed through).

It doesn't matter what you run within the Virtual Machine, your physical machine will only see a single application running - the VM software/Hypervisor/Similar itself.

However, a Virtual Machine - especially in Bridged networking mode runs identically as any physical machine on the network, this means, if it gets infected with any sort of malware such as Zombie/Spam/DDOS, it will still do the same job and if you get any virus that can infect other machines over the network, it could infect your machine.

(This question is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/29611/can-a-virus-from-a-virtualbox-vm-affect-the-host-computer/29615#29615), You may want to read to learn a little more, however, I think this is different enough not to be a duplicate)

Comment: Yes, not to mention the blue pill...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(malware)

Answer (score 1):

It's not isolated from the physical host, it's isolated from the logical host.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: The "logical host" is what makes the "physical host" a unique entity on a network domain. It's basically a combo of physical hardware+OS+configuration. So the VM is a unique logical host that consists of virtual HW+OS+config. However, the VM _can't_ be separated from it's physical host, or it would cease to exist, since the VM exists on top of a hypervisor, which runs on the physical hardware of the host.